# How to give inputs to the .sh in command line

Tags: echo

I have script abc.sh and it shows 4 options to user & 1 we need to choose.
at first we give inputs as 1 -for the first option
Now again it will show me 3 options and I have to choose as 1 -for second option.
Now at this time it will ask for the domain name and I need to give abc/abc@xyz - for third option option.
Now after this it will ask for the ENV details and I need to give ENV_NO.
So like this I want to give 4 different inputs to the existing script abc.sh.
So how can we give such above inputs automatically in single command for abc.sh.
We dont want to edit anything in the existing abc.sh

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "give options in echo in command line". Do you want to output the option chosen by the user?

Comment: not just by echo but any other way of giving automatic inputs to the script

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you're tying to do ?

Comment: I have script abc.sh and it asks the user for options to put inputs as

1 -for the first option

1 -for second option

abc/abc@xyz - for third option

option env - for 4th option. And I dont want to change in existing script just want to manage the inputs by command line.
At beginning it prompts for 4 options out of which we need to choose 1 and based on that it will given second prompt having 3 options and out of which we need to choose 1 and at third prompt is ask for domain name (abc/abc@xyz) and at 4th we need to provide env on which we need to execute

Comment: How do you distinguish option 1 from 2? They both have `1` as the key...

Comment: @JeffSchaller I know required options for my task to complete so I want to give hard coded values to finish my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an existing program that reads four things from its standard input, and you would want to provide input to the program without actually interacting with it.

You may prepare a text file (`input.txt`) that looks like this (the data is taken from the text of your question):

```
1
1
abc/abc@xyz
ENV_NO
```

You may then run your script like this:

```
$ ./abc.sh <input.txt
```

This will make the script read from the file instead of from the the keyboard interactively.  Any output from the script will still be displayed on the terminal (like questions for input), but the input will be read from the given file.

Instead of a file, you can also use a here-document:

```
./abc.sh <<END_INPUT
1
1
abc/abc@xyz
ENV_NO
END_INPUT
```

Comment: @ram This is what I attempted to do with the above answer. If there is something in the answer that you do not understand, then please let me know.

Comment: I have script abc.sh and it asks the user for options to put inputs as

1 -for the first option

1 -for second option

abc/abc@xyz - for third option

option env - for 4th option.
 
At beginning it prompts for 4 options out of which we need to choose 1 and based on that it will given second prompt having 3 options and out of which we need to choose 1 and at third prompt is ask for domain name (abc/abc@xyz) and at 4th we need to provide env on which we need to execute. Your suggestions are good but not the exact what I want. 
Please suggest as per the above described scenario. thanks

Comment: @ram It is clear what your code is currently doing. I have shown how to get the values of the command line arguments in the program and how to assign these to variables in the code. Which bit of my answer are you not following?

Comment: Yes I agree. But I dont want to add anything in abc.sh but just want to manage inputs through command line in one go. anyway of doing this? Also I have tried with echo "1 1 abc/abc@xyz env1" ./abc.sh but it takes only first char as input (first 1) and not continuing the next in same way

Comment: @ram See updated answer.

Comment: @ Kusalananda thanks a lot. It worked properly this time.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know this is what u looking for

```
read -r -p "`echo $'\n'`please enter your 1st option: " OPTION1
read -r -p "`echo $'\n'`please enter your 2nd option: " OPTION2
read -r -p "`echo $'\n'`please enter your domain: " OPTION3
read -r -p "`echo $'\n'`please enter your env: " OPTION4
echo "$OPTION1 $OPTION2 $OPTION3 $OPTION4"
```

Comment: No I just want to to give the options and script name in command line and script should be executed by taking all those inputs automatically and not accepting each input from user.

Comment: @ram Do you mean you want the script to take command-line arguments (as in, you'd run it with `./abc.sh firstoption secondoption abc/abc@xyz envoption`)? I'm also having a hard time figuring out what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes its like you said only. At beginning it prompts for 4 options out of which we need to choose 1 and based on that it will given second prompt having 3 options and out of which we need to choose 1 and at third prompt is ask for domain name (abc/abc@xyz) and at 4th we need to provide env on which we need to execute. Please suggest as per the above described scenario. thanks